# Combination of plural nouns

Tags: grammar, nouns

This question bugs for for a long period of time already and finally, I found a place to ask to native speakers.

Consider the following 2 situations:

**Situation 1:**

There are 10 firms.
Each of the 10 firms has 5 different products. (Say, product1, produt 2, ..., product 5)
Each of the 10 firms sets price for each of the 5 products in each period.

**Situation 2:**

There are 10 firms.
Each of the 10 firms has exactly 1 product.
(Say, firm 1 - product1, firm2 - produt 2, ..., firm 10 - product 1)
Each of the 10 firms sets price for its own only product.

---

When you say the following sentence *"10 **firms** set their **prices** in each period"*, which situation does this sentence describe, 1 or 2? By just reading this sentence, can you guess which situation the write refers to? In my opinion, this sentence includes both situations and just from it you can not deduce exactly which situation the write is referring to.

Would the following sentence be grammatically correct and at the same time precise for describing the first situation?

*"10 **firms** set their **price** in each period".*

Here, I used **price** in singular form to indicate that one firm sets only one price.

Basically, what I want to understand is when to use **firms and prices** at the same time and **firms and price** as the same time and what is difference between these two cases?

Comment: The main problem is that neither of you latter examples state "prices of what". If there is some prior context, the ambiguity will be resolved.

Comment: If you read the question well, it is very well described that I was talking about the price of the product of the firm.

Comment: You do not say how many products each of the firms produce, or whether the products are the same or not. I tried to read your question carefully but, unfortunately, the whole question has errors and is unclear to me. *"N number of firms"* is not idiomatic - we would say "N firms". However, as "N" is irrelevant, it would be clearer if you substituted a real number,

Comment: I changed according to your comment, Is it clear now?

Comment: (a) You'd not use singular 'price' here, though English sometimes does/may use a singular form where etically a plural would be expected (eg 'All three workers have already taken a break'). You _could_ use 'Each firm set its price' for situation (2).(b) '10 firms set their prices for 2017' could equally well refer to either situation.